# How to write an value to text field in application preferences settings ios?

Tags: ios, ipad, preferences, application-settings, root.plist

In application preference settings i have text field.
Behavior of textField:
1. When user enters text and launch application, the entered text is taken and processed.
2. when user clears textFiled and launch, the some text will be generated dynamically and has to put back the dynamically generated text to textField in settings preferences.

Is there any way to write the value to textField in application settings preferences ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values of Settings.app for your application are stored in the NSUserDefaults. You should be able to set them with:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:newValue forKey:@"theKeyYouDefinedInThePlist"]
```

Comment: No problem. If this answers your question, please mark the answer correct so others know where to look :)

Comment: I have the app read the value and use it in the app.  Its a url string.  But I want the user to be able to modify that string.  My question is, from where do I call this line cortez pasted above?  Currently the preferences are read in the appDidFinishLaunching because I need to get the url when the app loads.  But the url in the plist is just a placeholder.  The user needs to modify it to his own url value for the app to look for his server data.